# How to umount vdi mounted with vdfuse

Tags: virtualbox, fuse, umount

in my Ubuntu 12.10 machine install `virtualbox-fuse` and mount a `.vdi` file but now i dont know how to umounted

#### Command used to mount .vdi file

```
$ vdfuse -f /home/rkmax/win.vdi /mnt    
$ mount /mnt/Partition2 /home/rkmax/p2    
$ umount /home/rkmax/p2
```

but at last the .vdi are mounted, how i can umount?

Answer (score 0):

Unmount the windows partition by:

```
sudo umount /home/rkmax/p2
```

Umount the fuse filesystem by:

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

Note that if you get a massage like "target is busy", please make sure that no process is accessing these mount points.

Answer (score 0):

You unmount any(?) FUSE mount with `fusermount -u /the/mountpoint`. The user who mounted FUSE should be able to unmount it this way.